# How to snapshot a specific Index from Elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elasticsearch instances, instance 1 running on Server A, and instance 2 running on Server B.

I want to move a specific **index** from Server A to Server B only, without overwriting the indexes on Server B.

I have this curl command that does a whole snapshot

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup' -d '{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch",
    "compress": true
  }
}'
```

But I don't know how to snapshot/restore a specific index.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `curl` command you listed only sets up the `repository` and not the actual snapshot. Have a look at the [snapshot documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/modules-snapshots.html#snapshots-take-snapshot) that clearly states how to snapshot a specific index

You have created a repository named `backup`. So use the same when creating snapshots.

```
PUT /_snapshot/backup/my_snapshot?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "your_index_1,your_index_2",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```